# WEB INSTALL: Android apps

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, mdm, android

I am on the way to setup MAM server. I want to setup an environment more or less similar to google play where I could install the app in Google Play over the air. When the admin clicks Install on the web-server the app should get installed on the enrolled mobile devices. Is that possible with api's? If so what are all the api's should I use? Is there any open-source code available for this?

Comment: At the risk of sounding pedantic, Google Play doesn't work like that. Technically, it leaves the control of accepting the update to the user of each device. Also, you haven't told us your level/experience as a programmer and what you have tried thus far. Posting a question on StackOverflow isn't supposed to replace your attempt at trying to google for the answer yourself. By the way, you may want to take a look the developer of DevAppsDirect (nowadays he charges for setting up private app stores, but his solution may be the quickest to get set up) http://www.inappsquared.com/devappsdirect.html

Comment: Also take a look at TuneIn Radio http://tunein.com/ It's not an app store, but it uses the beta sdk of Google Play to allow remote over-the-air installs for google plus users (signed in with google+) who want to have the illusion of installing the TuneIn Android application from their non-android desktop computer (using the web site of TuneIn radio and the google play api) to directly install to their android device. But of course, that kind of ota install still means that you're installing things by using Google Play, so you're still bound by the terms and conditions of Google Play that way.

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding. I want to push the app in Google store into the enrolled mobile device from a admin webserver. The app should install without prompting the user or with just prompting for Google Play credentials.